# Java code build with maven and store the war in nexus and have to deploy to appserver

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jenkins, nexus

I need some help to automate my deployment tasks.
I am using a sample GITHUB project( JAVA)
Build tools-MAven
CI -jenkins, and NEXUS repository to store my artifact.

I have integrated Jenkins with GITHUB. And in maven pom.xml I have given the nexus repository details like (Release and snapshot).

When i trigger these job, the build tool is generating a war file(Let's say `1.0-RELEASE.war`) and deploying that war into nexus repository.

Now my requirement is to deploy that war file to an application server.
I have tried manually downloading the `1.0-RELEASE.WAR` from nexus and copy and paste to tomcat (webapps directory).Every thing is working fine. The war file is working fine.

Now I want to automate these manual process.

My requirement is.

1.Once the Build is successful , It have to store the artifacts to Nexus Repository(`1.0-Release.war`). These Task is automated.

2.I want to create a new deployment job.These Job have to tare care of pushing the Required war file from nexus(Have to pass these from jenkins like `1.0-RELEASE.war`) ,then we have to search in the NEXUS repository for (`1.0-RELEASE.war`). Once these war file is found, we have to deploy that war file to specified path(Tomcat app server in webapps dir).

Can some one help me with these automation task?

Answer (score 0):

1. Using Jenkins to store the artifact - Have a look at this [link](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/227256688-How-do-I-configure-the-Nexus-Jenkins-Plugin)
2. Deployment Job Config in Jenkins for Tomcat - Have a look at this [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin)